# How can I check if I'm properly grounded?

Tags: ground, grounding, safety, earth

I figured that if I used my trusty ol' calibrated Fluke 77 multimeter and:

1. Set it to Ω measurement
2. Measured between the ground terminal of an electrical outlet and a bare metal pipe fitting on a radiator (water borne heating) I would see.

I did so and got 5-6 ohms. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Test your multimeter, connect both tips at end of the cables together and look for the measured value. It should be less than 1 Ohm, ideally less than 0.1 Ohm. Then measure the pipe connection at two points in a a distance of about a centimeter or inch. This value should be as small as the value of both tips connected together. If not try to clean the pipe with sandpaper. You need a good clean metallic surface without oxidation.

Comment: Also swap the leads round and see if you get the same value. You may even get a negative one from induced currents in a big ground loop being greater than the test current your meter puts out (assuming that like many it uses a current source and voltmeter internally)

Comment: Thank you Uwe and Cris H for your comprehensive, well-informed answers!

Answer (score 4):

It depends for what purpose the ground is.

If for protecting your equipment from static electricity build-up on you, then it's perfectly low enough.

If it's for earth continutity for a mains protective earth, then if that 5 Ω measurement is real, it's not really low enough to conduct enough current in the case of a short-circuit fault to blow a fuse quickly.

There are a number of reasons a low current DC measurement could be faulty. You might have poor contact between your meter leads and the radiator, your meter might have a zero error, you might have contact potentials at the measuring points which are throwing the reading off. This is why protective earth continuity measurements are usually made with several amps of AC. If you have a low voltage AC source, like a soldering iron transformer, redo your measurement with that.

If your installation is actively bonding metal pipes and the protective earth (and most do in most jurisdictions in the world), then a real 5 Ω measurement shows you have a fault. Get your installation checked by an electrician.

Comment: Thank you Neil. You say: 'It depends for what purpose the ground is.' Both for personal safety and for EMC reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the protective-earth (PE) grounding is usually judged in two conditions:

1. resistance at a high fault current of e.g. 30 A. This is for safety and the voltage drop shouldn't exceed a certain value.
2. impedance at high frequency. This is mostly for EMC.

Unfortunately, your multimeter reading adresses neither, but gives a clue with respect to the first point of interest. My impression is that 5 Ω is a little high for solid fault current handling. I don't know this specific multimeter. Low resistances are typically measured with 4-wire sensing, because 2-wire multimeters can be rather inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you tobalt: you said: 'My impression is that 5 Ω is a little high for solid fault current handling.' Mine too.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, metal pipes within a building are required to be bonded to the building's grounding system. Thus, the resistance between an outlet's ground pin and the pipe should be small, (generally less than the 5 ohms you are measuring).

However, the resistance between the grounding wire and a test electrode stuck into the soil is permitted to be up to 25 ohms. So, if your pipe is NOT bonded to the electrical system's grounding wire, your measurement shows that the grounding system (probably) has a **resistance to ground** that is acceptable by US standards, even though the lack of bonding would be a violation of US code.

Whether or not your pipe is required to be bonded to the ground wiring, or whether the electrical connection to the electrical system's ground wire is permitted to be made through the physical earth/soil depends on the regulations in your juridiction.

Comment: Thaks Math Keeps Me Busy. I am Swedish but I am pretty sure standards here are comparable to US standards. The reason I asked is twofold; 1) personal safety and 2) the non-interference between apparatuses powered from electrical outlets. I suspect that a 5 ohm reading is too high for the second consideration.